# How to toggle (show/hide) element in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

This is my html element:

```
<ng-container>
    <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && expanded">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 25)}}
        <span>more</span>
    </span>
</ng-container>
```

It shows part of a message when row.messageText.length is greater than 30. I need the first span to show the entire message (by using *`row.messageText.substr()`*) after clicking the *more* span. I think that there is a solution by using *`(click)="toggle()"`* and setting some *true/false* values.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: yes you can do with click. did you try?

Comment: I don't know how. I'm new in Angular.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<ng-container>
    <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && expanded == false">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 25)}}
        <span (click)="expanded = true">more</span>
    </span>
<span *ngIf="expanded == true">{{row.messageText}}</span>
</ng-container>
```

and set expanded = false initially in your ts file

Comment: Where should I put it? In onInit() ?

Answer (score 25):

**In TS file**

```
showMyContainer: boolean = false;
```

**In HTML**

```
<button (click)="showMyContainer=!showMyContainer">Show/Hide</button>

<div *ngIf="showMyContainer">
     your code
</div>
```

See my **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjzx6h?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

*Happy to hear if someone got helped.*

Answer (score 7):

You can:

```
<ng-container>
    <div>
          <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length < 30">{{row.messageText}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && !expanded">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 25)}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && expanded">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 25)}}</span>
          <span (click)="toggle()">{{expanded?'less':'more'}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

component:

```
toggle(){
     this.expanded = !this.expanded;
}
```

Comment: This is the best way for me since in the toggle function you can perform function calls/dispatches etc based on the boolean value of expanded (i.e the toggle action by the user).



toggle() {
  this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  if (this.expanded) {
     return callFunctionOne();
  }
  return callFunctionTwo();
}

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in the question, you can pass the row to the function using click event as follows

```
 <span (click)="enableSpan(row)">more</span>
```

and then inside typescript.

```
enableSpan(row:any){
   row.expand = true;
}
```

and the corresponding HTML would be

```
<span *ngIf="row.expand">{{row.messageText}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
<span *ngIf="row.messageText"> {{(row.messageText.length >= 30 && expanded == false)? row.messageText.substr(0, 25) : row.messageText}}
   <span style="color: blue;" *ngIf="row.messageText.length >= 30" (click)=" expanded = !expanded ">{{(!expanded)? 'more' : 'less'}}</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="top5" *ngFor="let feedback of topFeedbacks; index as i" >
      <ng-container>
        <div style="margin-left: 5%;">
              <span *ngIf="feedback && feedback.length < 80"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{feedback}}</span>
              <span *ngIf="feedback && feedback.length >= 80 && !expanded[i]"> <i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{feedback.substr(0, 75)}}</span>
              <span *ngIf="feedback && feedback.length >= 80 && expanded[i]"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{feedback.substr(0, feedback.length)}}</span> 
              <label>&nbsp;</label>
              <a  *ngIf="feedback && feedback.length >= 80" class="toggle-button" (click)="toggle(i)">{{expanded[i]?' ...Show less':' ...Show more'}}</a>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</d
iv>
```

Comment: declare expanded={} is your .ts file

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly easy fix for this problem.
In my example, i just use it to show, but a toggle or whatever is possible using the same method obviously.

I like this solution because it is all valid and all template :)

```
<ng-container>
    <div data-expand="false" #expandWrap>
        <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30 && expandWrap.dataset.show == 'false'">{{row.messageText.substr(0, 25)}}
            <span (click)="expandWrap.dataset.show = 'true'">more</span>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="expandWrap.dataset.show == 'true'">{{row.messageText}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

I made [a small demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expand-template-init?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.html) on how this works