# How TO - Read More Read/Less Button with angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

I'm looking for a solution to add a button read more and less in my long text with angular 5 or I need to convert  this code with Js to angular 6:

readMoreButton.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.service-info').hide();
    $('.read-less').hide();
      $('.read-more').click(function(){
          $(this).hide();
          $(this).next().show();
          $(this).next().next().show();
        })
      $('.read-less').click(function(){
        $(this).prev().hide();
          $(this).prev().prev().show();
          $(this).hide();
      })
  })
```

readMoreButton.html

```
<a class="read-more">Read More </a>
  <div class="service-info">

    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
  </div>
<a class="read-less">Read Less</a>


<div class="separator"><hr></div>


<a class="read-more">Read More </a>
  <div class="service-info">

    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>
    <p> Lorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaretLorem ipusum dolorem isaret</p>

  </div>
<a class="read-less">Read Less</a>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you tell what is not done in your code and what is the problem that you are facing

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819312/angular-2-read-more-directive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to toggle (show/hide) element in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528880/how-to-toggle-show-hide-element-in-angular-4)

Comment: Thnx All For your Ideas

Answer (score 3):

**How I achieved this**

**Step 1:**

```
<button type="button" (click)="alterDescriptionText()">
   { showShortDesciption ? 'SHOW ALL': 'SHOW LESS' }}
 </button>
```

**Step 2:** (In Your .component.ts File)

```
 showShortDesciption = true

 alterDescriptionText() {
    this.showShortDesciption = !this.showShortDesciption
 }
```

**Step 3:**

```
<div [ngClass]="{'show-less': showShortDesciption}">
      <!-- Your Text Here -->
</div
```

**Step 4:**

```
.show-less {
    height: 4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Basically i'm altering the height of div on button click

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the angular plugin "@minni/read-more". Check out the link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@minni/read-more). It's quite a simple and easy-to-use plugin.